# Unable to login Using Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I am using **Gatling Tool**. Initially, I have to login to service. I am trying to login on "login.salesforce.com".

This is my scala code. I am unable to login. Guide me where I am doing wrong.

```js
package default

import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._


class requestUser extends Simulation { 

 
 val httpProtocol = http.baseURL("http://login.salesforce.com")
 
 val headers_1 = Map(
  "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
  "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate",
  "Cache-Control" -> "no-cache",
  "Origin" -> "https://testingapp-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com",
  "Pragma" -> "no-cache",
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")

 val headers_2 = Map(
  "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
  "Cache-Control" -> "no-cache",
  "Pragma" -> "no-cache",
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")


 val Test = exec(http("request 1")
     .get("/?stbdtimeout=1&login_hint=opareshbhai%40steelbrick.com")
     .headers(headers_2))
     .exec(http("Login")
      .post("/")
      .headers(headers_1)
      .formParam("pqs", "%3Fstbdtimeout%3D1%26login_hint%3Dabcd%2540steelbrick.com")
      .formParam("un", "abcd%40gmail.com")
      .formParam("width", "1536")
      .formParam("height", "960")
      .formParam("hasRememberUn", "true")
      .formParam("startURL", "")
      .formParam("loginURL", "")
      .formParam("loginType", "")
      .formParam("useSecure", "true")
      .formParam("local", "")
      .formParam("lt", "standard")
      .formParam("qs", "r%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flogin.salesforce.com%252F")
      .formParam("locale", "")
      .formParam("oauth_token", "")
      .formParam("oauth_callback", "")
      .formParam("login", "")
      .formParam("serverid", "")
      .formParam("display", "page")
      .formParam("username", "abcd%40gmail.com")
      .formParam("ExtraLog", "%255B%257B%2522width%2522%3A1536%257D%2C%257B%2522height%2522%3A960%257D%2C%257B%2522language%2522%3A%2522en-US%2522%257D%2C%257B%2522offset%2522%3A-5.5%257D%2C%257B%2522scripts%2522%3A%255B%257B%2522size%2522%3A249%2C%2522summary%2522%3A%2522if%2520%28self%2520%3D%3D%2520top%29%2520%257Bdocument.documentElement.style.v%2522%257D%2C%257B%2522size%2522%3A568%2C%2522summary%2522%3A%2522var%2520SFDCSessionVars%3D%257B%255C%2522server%255C%2522%3A%255C%2522https%3A%2F%2Flogin.sales%2522%257D%2C%257B%2522url%2522%3A%2522https%3A%2F%2Ftestingapp-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com%2Fjslibrary%2FSfdcSessionBase198.js%2522%257D%2C%257B%2522url%2522%3A%2522https%3A%2F%2Ftestingapp-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com%2Fjslibrary%2FLoginHint198.js%2522%257D%2C%257B%2522size%2522%3A26%2C%2522summary%2522%3A%2522LoginHint.hideLoginForm%28%29%3B%2522%257D%2C%257B%2522size%2522%3A36%2C%2522summary%2522%3A%2522LoginHint.getSavedIdentities%28false%29%3B%2522%257D%2C%257B%2522url%2522%3A%2522https%3A%2F%2Ftestingapp-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com%2Fjslibrary%2Fbaselogin2.js%2522%257D%2C%257B%2522url%2522%3A%2522https%3A%2F%2Ftestingapp-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com%2Fjslibrary%2FLoginMarketingSurveyResponse.js%2522%257D%2C%257B%2522size%2522%3A397%2C%2522summary%2522%3A%2522function%2520handleLogin%28%29%257Bdocument.login.un.value%3Ddoc%2522%257D%255D%257D%2C%257B%2522scriptCount%2522%3A9%257D%2C%257B%2522iframes%2522%3A%255B%2522https%3A%2F%2Fc.salesforce.com%2Flogin-messages%2Fpromos.html%3Fr%3Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Flogin.salesforce.com%25252F%2522%2C%2522https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Flogin%2Fsessionserver190.html%2522%255D%257D%2C%257B%2522iframeCount%2522%3A2%257D%255D")
      .formParam("pw", "***********")
      .formParam("Login", "Log+In")
      .check(status.is(200), status.not(401))
     )
          .pause(5)

        .exec(http("set")
       .get("/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp?setupid=ForceCom")
       .headers(headers_2)
       .check(currentLocation.is("https://google.com"))
       
      )
    var scn = scenario("scn").exec(Test)

 setUp(
  scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)

}
```

& This is my log file:

```js
Simulation default.requestUser started...

================================================================================

2016-04-04 12:36:39                                           0s elapsed
---- scn -----------------------------------------------------------------------

[                                                                          ]  0%

          waiting: 1      / active: 0      / done:0
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------

> Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )


================================================================================



================================================================================

2016-04-04 12:36:44                                           5s elapsed
---- scn -----------------------------------------------------------------------

[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%

          waiting: 0      / active: 1      / done:0
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------

> Global                                                   (OK=4      KO=0     )

> request 1                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )

> request 1 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )

> Login                                                    (OK=1      KO=0     )

> Login Redirect 1                                         (OK=1      KO=0     )

================================================================================


12:36:48.638 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandlerActor - Request 'set' failed: currentLo
cation.find.is(https://google.com), but actually found http://login.salesforce.c
om/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp?setupid=ForceCom

================================================================================

2016-04-04 12:36:48                                           9s elapsed
---- scn -----------------------------------------------------------------------

[##########################################################################]100%

          waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done:1
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------

> Global                                                   (OK=4      KO=1     )

> request 1                                                (OK=1      KO=0     )

> request 1 Redirect 1                                     (OK=1      KO=0     )

> Login                                                    (OK=1      KO=0     )

> Login Redirect 1                                         (OK=1      KO=0     )

> set                                                      (OK=0      KO=1     )

---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------

> currentLocation.find.is(https://google.com), but actually foun      1 (100.0%)

d http://login.salesforce.com/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp?set...
================================================================================


Simulation finished
Parsing log file(s)...
Parsing log file(s) done
Generating reports...

================================================================================

---- Global Information --------------------------------------------------------

> request count                                          5 (OK=4      KO=1     )

> min response time                                    347 (OK=356    KO=347   )

> max response time                                   2331 (OK=2331   KO=347   )

> mean response time                                   877 (OK=1009   KO=347   )

> std deviation                                        758 (OK=794    KO=0     )

> response time 50th percentile                        421 (OK=676    KO=347   )

> response time 75th percentile                        931 (OK=1281   KO=347   )

> mean requests/sec                                  0.525 (OK=0.42   KO=0.105 )

---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------

> t < 800 ms                                             2 ( 40%)
> 800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                   1 ( 20%)
> t > 1200 ms                                            1 ( 20%)
> failed                                                 1 ( 20%)
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------

> currentLocation.find.is(https://google.com), but actually foun      1 (100.0%)

d http://login.salesforce.com/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp?set...
================================================================================
```

Comment: Have you tried using Assertions API in Gatling to assert the response body of login request.

Comment: No. I haven't. Can you tell me what changes are require?

Comment: JMeter has builtin assertions elements in it which I use to achieve this objective. You can look into Gatling documentation to see if they provide similar support .. http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/general/assertions.html

Comment: Thanks. But I guess -Gatling assertions functionality is limited to response time & failed request.

Answer (score 1):

why are you expecting to login "http://www.google.com".That's why your  not able to login salesforce and getting an error log

"currentLocation.find.is(https://google.com), but actually found http://login.salesforce.com/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp?".

Rearrange your code like this and I hope this will work for you

`.exec(http("set")
.get("/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp?setupid=ForceCom")
.headers(headers_2) 
)`